# When i put my java code on aws lambda , it gives error "Class not found"

Tags: aws-lambda

When I put my Java code on AWS Lambda, it gives an error `class not found`. The code is

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

        // TODO: implement your handler
        return "Hello from Lambda!";
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be great if you [format your code first](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44653791/edit)

Comment: which class wasn't found???

Comment: class is  LambdaFunctionHandler